# is it is possible to disable the windows keys using java

Tags: java

is it is possible to disable the windows keys and alt+tab using java ...

Comment: Some keystrokes are not possible to trap unless you use a kernel mode device driver. Why would Windows allow an application to prevent you from switching away from the current task?

Comment: While you have a point for Alt+Tab, there's actually a good case for disabling the Win keys in full-screen apps such as games.  I can't tell you how many times I've accidentally bumped the left-hand Win key in a game, only to have the whole screen minimize.

Comment: @Will - presumably, the Windows designers think otherwise ...

Comment: For some reason Ctrl-Alt-Del is trapped when running in DirectDraw exlusive mode, but not other keys...

Answer (score 13):

You can use JNA to achieve this.

Include jna.jar and platform.jar on the classpath and create the following class.
This class disables left windows key (0x5B) and right windows key (0x5C). So you can add other codes at the switch case statement.

Call KeyHook.blockWindowsKey() as soon as possible when your application starts.
On the other side, call unblockWindowsKey() at app shutdown.

Since the code is only executed when isWindows() is true, you can always call KeyHook.blockWindowsKey(), even when running on another OS.

```
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HMODULE;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HHOOK;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.LowLevelKeyboardProc;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.MSG;


    public class KeyHook {
        private static HHOOK hhk;
        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc keyboardHook;
        private static User32 lib;

        public static void blockWindowsKey() {
            if (isWindows()) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        lib = User32.INSTANCE;
                        HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
                        keyboardHook = new LowLevelKeyboardProc() {
                            public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT info) {
                                if (nCode >= 0) {
                                    switch (info.vkCode){
                                        case 0x5B:
                                        case 0x5C:
                                            return new LRESULT(1);
                                        default: //do nothing
                                    }
                                }
                                return lib.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, info.getPointer());
                            }
                        };
                        hhk = lib.SetWindowsHookEx(13, keyboardHook, hMod, 0);

                        // This bit never returns from GetMessage
                        int result;
                        MSG msg = new MSG();
                        while ((result = lib.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0)) != 0) {
                            if (result == -1) {
                                break;
                            } else {
                                lib.TranslateMessage(msg);
                                lib.DispatchMessage(msg);
                            }
                        }
                        lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }

        public static void unblockWindowsKey() {
            if (isWindows() && lib != null) {
                lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
            }
        }

        public static boolean isWindows(){
            String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
            return (os.indexOf( "win" ) >= 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Are there any way to disable ctrl-alt-del? Your code works well but cant block ctrl-alt-del. Task manager comes up

Comment: How to destroy this thread? After I run the `unblockWindowsKey()`, this thread is still running in background

Comment: @NMNaufaldo You can store the Thread object in a field in the class and interrupt it when disabling the key blocker. In the while loop, you can then also break when the thread is interrupted. Alternatively, you can mark the thread as a daemon thread to allow the JVM to terminate, even when this thread is still running.