# How do I disable Windows functions in Java?

Tags: java, windows, swing

I have an application which runs in fullscreen mode but I want to make it so when the user presses Alt-Tab, Windows key + Tab or Ctrl+Alt+Delete, nothing happens.
I have tried doing requestFocus() every frame so if the user tabs out, it tabs back in but it doesn't do anything. Also JFrame.setAlwaysOnTop() doesn't make it always on top if the user tabs out. So how would I prevent the user from tabbing out?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you imagine what it would be like if every programmer decided that their program must defy the conventions of the host OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to disable some key combinations - [is it is possible to disable the windows keys using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486167/is-it-is-possible-to-disable-the-windows-keys-using-java)

But, you *cannot* disable or override alt+ctrl+delete.

You *shouldn't* generally disable these key combinations though even if you can. If a user wants to alt+tab, let them. Otherwise you'll have some angry and fleeting users.

Comment: Though I think you can kill the task manager process whenever it appears.

Comment: I don't think it brings up the task manager in all versions of Windows. I think in Windows 7 it brings up a list of options, one of which is the task manager. Either way, you shouldn't do this.

Comment: Dang it. I was hoping to be able to "lock" my computer so when I'm away, others who I don't want to use it, can't use it. Since this program was really made just to be used by me. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: why not use the os to lock it and your program can continue to run