# Is it possible to lock the Windows OS desktop using Java (Swing)?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to make a small application, similar to a cyber cafe software.

To be specific, what i want to do is that once the app starts, you can't do anything in the computer, and it's impossible to cease the locking, (Alt + F4, Ctrl + Alt + Del, Task Manager, etc.) unless you put up a certain username and password, and once a specific amount of time has passed by, the software will lock the computer again.

I am pretty much a novice in Java, so i couldn't find any answers that i could understand or that were what i was looking for. Is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that's not possible. At least not with pure java. The relevant parts for this need to interfer with the OS in a way, that java can't provide.

Comment: I doubt it. Swing's goal is not to be a blackmail trojan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably need to use JNA to do things like that, or just change to C++/C#.

Such example as this:

```
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HMODULE;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HHOOK;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.LowLevelKeyboardProc;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.MSG;


    public class KeyHook {
        private static HHOOK hhk;
        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc keyboardHook;
        private static User32 lib;

        public static void blockWindowsKey() {
            if (isWindows()) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        lib = User32.INSTANCE;
                        HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
                        keyboardHook = new LowLevelKeyboardProc() {
                            public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT info) {
                                if (nCode >= 0) {
                                    switch (info.vkCode){
                                        case 0x5B: //Around here would be where you add all your 0x key codes
                                        case 0x5C:
                                            return new LRESULT(1);
                                        default: //do nothing
                                    }
                                }
                                return lib.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, info.getPointer());
                            }
                        };
                        hhk = lib.SetWindowsHookEx(13, keyboardHook, hMod, 0);

                        // This bit never returns from GetMessage
                        int result;
                        MSG msg = new MSG();
                        while ((result = lib.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0)) != 0) {
                            if (result == -1) {
                                break;
                            } else {
                                lib.TranslateMessage(msg);
                                lib.DispatchMessage(msg);
                            }
                        }
                        lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }

        public static void unblockWindowsKey() {
            if (isWindows() && lib != null) {
                lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
            }
        }

        public static boolean isWindows(){
            String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
            return (os.indexOf( "win" ) >= 0);
        }
    }
```

(That was not mine, ill explain in a bit)
Then see if it is running Windows by 'KeyHook.isWindows()'.

If it is, use things like 'blockWindowsKey()' or make your own functions like it. I put a comment where you'd change the key code.

*FYI possible duplicate of [is it is possible to disable the windows keys using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486167/is-it-is-possible-to-disable-the-windows-keys-using-java)*
Thats where the code came from.

Comment: It would be better if you used C anyway, hence Windows is coded in C++/#.

Comment: I see. Well, i think i'll have to do some changes. Thanks a bunch!