# Disable some PC keyboard keys using Java

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard

I'm working on a software project using Java. I'm also using JavaFX for it's GUI. When this software is run on a PC, it should lock the screen of the PC until a valid pin is entered.

I want some keyboard keys such as the control, alternate and windows key to be disabled when the software is run.

How can I do this?

Comment: In short, you can't.

Comment: I don't think there's any way *in Java* to do that.  You will have to invoke some native component.

Comment: I tried using this [KeyHook Java class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7793900/4338203) but I get this error:    incompatible types: Pointer cannot be converted to LPARAM at this line of code:    return lib.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, info.getPointer());

Comment: See: [securing windows as a kiosk](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/07/25/Securing-Windows-For-Use-As-A-Kiosk).  It's not exactly what you are looking for, as it disables keys via windows registry hacks and a reboot without the use of Java.  But then again, depending on the key you want to disable, you probably won't find a way to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Are you making a virus?:)

Answer (score 0):

A very ghetto way to remove SOME use of keys is using Java.awt.Robot, but it WONT stop OS specific hooks like CTRL + ALT + DELETE, but it will stop Alt + Tab working.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
while(true)
{
  r.keyRelease(VK.ALT);
  r.keyRelease(VK.TAB);
  //etc etc
}
```